# Why does pexpect duplicate commands in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

I am using pexpect to send this command:

```
fmsadmin list files -s
```

With this interactive program

```
[('username \\(.+\\):', 'userName\n'), ('password:', 'invalidPW\n'),
('username \\(.+\\):', 'userName\n'), ('password:', 'validPW\n')]
```

Like this:

```
run( cmd, events=program, timeout=20)
```

Which ends with 4 pairs of username & password instead of 2:

```
username (userName): userName
password:
fmsadmin: Permission denied, please try again.
username (userName): userName
password:
fmsadmin: Permission denied, please try again.
username (userName): userName
password:
fmsadmin: Permission denied, please try again.
username (userName): userName
password:
fmsadmin: Permission denied.
Error: 9 (Access denied)
```

Is there something wrong with the structure of the interactive program?  Maybe there is a different timer to wait for the phrases to come up?  Why am I getting 4 pairs when I'm only programming 2 pairs.  BTW, for me, each of these smaller programs for username and for password are separate functions.  When I do a 1 pair version of this functionality it works.  IOW:

This works:

```
[('username \\(.+\\):', 'userName\n'), ('password:', 'validPW\n')]
```

For the interactive program directly above I do:

```
[iUserName(), iPassword()]
```

The interactive program at the top is produced by doing:

```
[iUserName(), invPassword(), iUserName(), iPassword()]
```

I only include these to indicate that consistent programs are being generated by the code.  I believe the output examples are what we should be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

`pexpect.run(events=[(pat1, reply1), (pat2, reply2)])`, does not first match pattern 1 and send reply 1, then wait to match pattern 2 and send reply 2.
Instead, it attempts to match any of the patterns all the time, though it does test them in the order given.

So there is never any point in repeating the same pattern, as the first occurence of the pattern will always be the only one to match, if at all.

If you want to do a sequence of similar matches, you will have to resort to the usual `spawn()`, `expect()`, `send()`, `expect()`, `send()`,... mechanism.

Comment: Well that is sad.  I had this working with the unix expect command which does follow the order of 'program' that is created.  I'm testing software otherwise I wouldn't even want to do this.  One valid account and password is good for real world work.  Using the expect(), send() is very clumsy.  Hummm I suppose I could create a loop and pull off one item from my list at a time and send it to run.  That should simulate the same thing.  Wonder who I can get an SCR into.

Comment: doh... of course that won't work.  You issue the command at the same time as the program.  Ugg... it would have to be an SCR or using the expect(), send() method.  I don't like writing specific pieces of code for the every single unique test I write.  I generally create the array and send it off to a very minimal runner class that I have written.  Ugg more thought.